# Show only IPv6 using PHP

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ipv6

I have a Ubuntu VPS that supports both IPv4 and IPv6. I have set up a PHP site on it to check the IP address of the visitor.
My code:

```
    function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

It only returns the IPv4, not the IPv6, even though I have both.

How can I make the code show IPv6 by default if the visitor has one?

Regards

Comment: You can only see the IP that the visitor uses in its connection. Remember that IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate, incompatible protocols. The connection will use one or the other, and you do not know if the visitor also has the other, or AppleTalk, IPX, etc. also configured on it.

Comment: @RonMaupin I have both IPv6 and IPv4. When I check my IP on Google and other sites, they show the IPv6, but when I do on my site, it only shows the IPv4.

Comment: What I am saying is that a TCP connection only uses one or the other, not both, and you can only tell the protocol used by the TCP connection, not any other protocol that the other end of the connection may also have configured.

Comment: @RonMaupin Oh, would it be possible to force IPv6 connection if it's available?

Comment: You cannot force a host you do not control to use a particular IP if you offer both. Most hosts will default to using IPv6 first, if available on both sides. Do you have both A and AAAA records in DNS for your device? You also may be able to do something like embed a one pixel image in your web page that requires IPv6 to get to it, and that would force an IPv6 connection if the host browsing supports it.